# cannot upgrade pip in MAC OS

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to upgrade pip using the command

```
pip install -U pip
```

but it says:

"Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages"

and using the command

```
pip --version
```

shows that it is a very old one:

pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

My question: how can I upgrade pip?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling both pip and python 3.4

then installing python 3.7 and 
then reinstalling pip

therefore, I have pip 18.0 :)